# Is there any way to bind 'any' redirect (link/refresh/etc) through an authentication script?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, apache

**Context:** I'm putting together a social network sort of thing, and I want to be able to validate any refresh or redirect with by pushing the user to another script before reaching their destination..I thought about using a 'get' method, but that would require me to manually set each link as a form, either that or some kind of ajax script however I am not too familiar with ajax to know if that is altogether possible.

Is there some kind of apache rule I can implement that applies a script to each redirect/refresh ?

**Platform:** I am using php/mysql and am not too terrible at ajax/js

**Why:** I want to be able to validate the user's logged in information aswell as track their page visits. (the latter I am sure must be ajax related)

Any Ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript (or jQuery) to cycle through all the links on the page and add an onClick attribute pointing to a handler function.

```
<a href="www.example.com/somepage.html" onClick="tracker(this);">Go Here</a>
```

Then you can define a custom tracker function

```
function tracker(link){
  // Pass data to some php page with AJAX
  // Return true for success (user will move to the selected page)
  // Return false to cancel the click (will do nothing)
}
```

To set it up using jQuery, it would look something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
  var attr = $(this).attr('onClick');
  if (typeof attr === 'undefined' || attr === false){
    $(this).attr('onClick', 'tracker(this);');
  }else{
    // onClick already set
  }
});
```

You could probably use jQuery's native event functions to bind an onClick event as well.

Comment: This looks /exactly/ like what I want! 

however i'm not too sure how to get jquery to cycle through all the links. 

Also, what if there is an already set onclick event?

Comment: I'll add it to my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Include a script on the top of every page that check login information using sessions (I hope you know what I'm saying) and if they are not present, it redirects user to a login page. In that same script, you can also track visit as you want.

Comment: that doesnt work when the outward links arent mine, i.e if there is a link to http://www.google.com I want to be able to track that

Comment: Oh, in this case I think there is no other way that put a script between you and the destination URL. For example, I think Facebook do something like that. You have to change all external links to something like: yourscript.php?url=externalurl. Then, on yourscript.php you do all your stuff, and at the end you use header("Location: ". $_GET["url"]) to redirect user to destination.

Comment: PS: you can use javascript (jQuery or so) to cycle on all external links on your page to automagically change their href attribute to place your modified url. But here I cannot help you.

Comment: hahahahaha damn you facebook for being so smart! *shakes fists*, yeah that's what I kind of thought it would have to be but still, kinda sucks but oh well.